# Why does this ZIO layer composition not compile?

Tags: scala, zio

Obviously, this wasn't exactly my use case, but here is the MCVE, demonstrating the problem:

```
  def bad = {
    val in: ZLayer[Any, Any, String] = null
    val layer: ZLayer[String with Int with Double, Any, Double] = null
    val out: ZLayer[Any & Int, Any, Double] = in >>> layer
  }
```

This *should* work, right? Intellij agrees, and says everything is right ... until you hit compile.
The compiler says:

```
 found   : zio.ZLayer[String with Int with Double,Any,Double]
 required: zio.ZLayer[String with Any with Int,Any,Double]
```

What??? Why?

Interestingly, if you change the first `Double` to a `String` (or to anything else for that matter if you adjust the `out` type), it works fine:

```
  def good = {
    val in: ZLayer[Any, Any, String] = null
    val layer: ZLayer[String with Int with String, Any, Double] = null
    val out: ZLayer[Any & Int, Any, Double] = in >>> layer
  }
```

Any ideas? I am starting to think, this is a compiler bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some type tetris :) Let's visualize, what's going on here:

| layer | requires | provides |
| --- | --- | --- |
| in | - | String |
| layer | String, Int, Double | Double |
| in >>> layer | Int, Double | Double |
| out | Int | Double |

When you compose `in` and `layer` to `in >>> layer`, `in` eliminates `String` from what is required by `layer`, but the rest (`Int` and `Double`) is still required by the resulting layer. However, the type annotation on `out` in your `bad` example states that it only requires `Int`, which is not correct.

Note that there are different ways to fix the error in `bad`:

1. Add `Double` to what's required by `out`
2. Remove `Double` from what's required by `layer`
3. Add `Double` to what's provided by `in`

Seems that the compiler considers the type of `out` fix, and suggests the second solution, which is exactly what you did in `good`.

Comment: Ugh .. you are right ... looks like I oversimplified it trying to come up with a small example :/ 
In my actual case, there was no type annotation on the out at all, and it seemed to be complaining about the argument to `>>>`  ... But _this one_ does compile without the type annotation, I just overlooked it.

Comment: One tip: a super useful tool, when dealing with confusing error messages involving ZIO types is [zio-clippy](https://github.com/hmemcpy/zio-clippy). It's a fantastic scala compiler plugin that helps you understand, what's actually wrong without having to manually dissect those horrible type mismatch error messages.